# Divide Meteor files into client and server folders

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm writing a program with meteor and I'm wondering how one would go about splitting a single meteor JavaScript file, like one that is generated upon the 'meteor' command, into a client and server folder (client.js, server.js, etc). I haven't found any good guides. Does anybody know of any?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create two directories, `client` and `server`. Then put the frontend codes in `client` and the backend codes in `server`. Take a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: I tried simply partitioning it based on where it said isClient and isServer but to no avail. I'll look into your link though. Thanks

Comment: Great, I got it to work. I was a bit led astray by the parties demo, as they used a model.js. You don't need that. Thanks again.